# C# : How to get SSL handshake response before proceeding to HttpWebrequest?

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I want to know my SSL handshake response before making any HttpWebRequest so that in case of failure I wont be making any HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I think the handshake is always part of a request, why not send a dummy request to a status page or simmilar

Comment: Surely it will fail to make the request if the handshake fails?

Comment: for Dummy request let say for a GET request will I be getting any exceptions If I forcefully try to fail handshake like changing the date can make handshake to fail.

Comment: @john is there a way by which I can forcefully fail the request due to handshake I have already tried changing the system date but it didn't worked.

Comment: What do you want to know of the SSL handshake? What protocol was negotiated? Something else?

Comment: Just tried changing the date. It fails the certificate for me. You did change the date outside of the validity range for the certificate, right?

Comment: @john after changing the date it fails for me in the browser but not with my c# code to make get request.

Answer (score 0):

If the SSL handshake fails, it will throw an exception.  However, if you'd really like to do some of the grunt work and get fancy, check our the [SslStream class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I've included some of the sample code from there below.  This will allow you to do more fine-grained security stuff, if you have some use case for that.

```
    // Create a TCP/IP client socket.
    // machineName is the host running the server application.
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName, 443);
    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

    // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
        client.GetStream(), 
        false, 
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback (ValidateServerCertificate), 
        null
        );

    // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
    try 
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
    } 
    catch (AuthenticationException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine ("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
        client.Close();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Really no reason to go to SslStream for this - you can set a ServerCertificateValidationCallback on HttpWebRequest as well (and on HttpClient).